# Folder structure of flask app with machine learning component

Tags: python, flask

I am developing a flask based web app. A user can enter the car specifications and will get predictions of the price of the car based on a machine learning model.

I was following many tutorials on how to create a web app but I feel confused on where to put configurations on machine learning component and how to structure the code correctly.

I have the following folder structure of my project:

```
├── webapp         
│   ├── app        
│       ├── static
│       ├── templates
│       ├── routes.py
│       ├── utils.py --> utils function that are used in 'routes.py'
│   ├── src
│       ├── ml_utils.py --> functions for machine learning component
│   ├── else stuff
```

in routes.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import numpy as np
from app.utils import find_freshest_model, convert_to_float, process_features_info_for_option_html, create_features
from src.ml_utils import load_features_info

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html', car_type=option_values['car type'])


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    #order features in a correct way according to order in features_info
    features = create_features(request, features_info)
    prediction = model.predict(features)

    return render_template('index.html',
                           prediction_text='Your predicted car price is {} Euro'.format(prediction), quality=option_values['quality'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    model_file = find_freshest_model() 
    features_info = load_features_info() # containts correct order of the features and categorization of features (numerical, categorical)
    option_values = process_features_info_for_option_html(features_info['features_dummy'])

    model = joblib.load(model_file)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Task and Questions:
I want to prepare my app for production and to structure it better.

1. Should I put in **init**.py following code?
2. Regarding the code under `if __name__ == '__main__':`. Should I create a class modelConfigs, put it into models.py? In **init.py** I import modelConfigs and will initialize it routes.py.

models.py

```
from src.ml_utils import load_features_info
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from app.utils import find_freshest_model, process_features_info_for_option_html


class ModelConfigs:
    __tablename__ = 'modelConfigs'
    model = joblib.load(find_freshest_model())
    features_info = load_features_info()
    option_values = process_features_info_for_option_html(features_info['features_dummy'])
```

**init.py**:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from app.models import ModelConfigs

model_config = ModelConfigs

from app import routes
```

routes.py:

```
from flask import request, render_template
import numpy as np
from app.utils import create_features
from app import app, model_config



@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html', car_type=option_values['car type'])


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    features = create_features(request, model_config.features_info)
    prediction = np.expm1(model_config.model.predict(features))    
    return render_template('index.html',
                           prediction_text='Your predicted car price is {} Euro'.format(prediction), quality=option_values['quality'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Flask has a feature called, "Blueprints," which allows you, separate your application into several folders so that routes and views can be kept more neatly in their own folder, yet allow one python file to call on them each individually as needed.

I mention this because it's one of the parts of Flask that Flask likes to highlight. What this does is allows you to keep your project structure cleaner, yet at the same time completely customizeable. Hypothetically you could build your own machine learning pipeline right within a blueprint, I can't think of a specific application for that - but who knows? The capability is there.

Outside of blueprints, from what I have read in a lot of different blogs and practice myself, generally for a small machine learning project, you might start off with just throwing a few things into /src since that's the, "source" folder where you put the types of things that go on the server. However you may quickly outgrow that, and need to separate your /src folder into several different folders which actually represent a legitimate data science project or pipeline structure of some type.

One way you might consider structuring your folder would be the following:

```
└── src
│   ├── features
│   ├── preparation
│   ├── preprocessing
│   ├── evaluation
│   └── js
└── tests
│   └── unit_tests
└── models
│   └── retrained_models
└── data
│   └── raw_data
│   └── processed_data
│   └── user_input_data
└── pipeline
│   └── model_retraining_automation_scripts
└── docs
    └── Documentation
    └── Notebooks
```

All of the above assumes you are storing everything on the server itself, which is restrictive from a data engineering perspective. Servers typically are more expensive, they run on SSD's or whatever. So if you start to grow in size and have massive amounts of data, you would need to perhaps store that in a document store such as AWS S3.  If that's the case, you could think about that folder structure above to keep various operations and .py files that would perform similar functions on a small scale and translate that into a larger scale, however you might need to start storing training models as actual binaries in a database, or growing even larger, in S3 buckets, with some way of tracking what is going where, presumably a relational database.

Comment: Your answer has some formatting problems. Try to improve that. Use `\`` brackets for paths and code fragments. **To start from a new line use *double space* at the end of the line - the question'll be way more clear than using `Enter` everywhere.**

Comment: This was my first time using Stackoverflow to answer a question. When I hit the, "enter code" brackets button { } it created a block which I had assumed was equivalent to ``` . ``` type code exiting. Does that button not work?

Comment: Yes, it works. But you insert your tree as text and used `Enter` to start a new line. Now, you have used code brackets and that's not bad but *still* the tree takes too much space on the page because you just copy the text -  you didn't delete the useless line breaks. Just try to compress it.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. Done.